# how to use viewbinding with viewmodel in layout?

Tags: android

I'm  trying to use viewBinding with viewmodel in layout. I can use viewBinding when not using viewmodel in layout. But the problem started when adding the layout tag in xml.
I can't inflate ActivityMainBinding after that. How to solve it? Is that impossible to use viewmodel with viewBinding?

*Error*

```
Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

*Main Activity*

```
    lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //tried but not working

       /* val viewGroup = findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,viewGroup,false)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.bind(view)
        setContentView(binding.root)*/
        
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    }
```

*activity_main*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.haii.graphqldemo.MainViewModel"/>
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I forgot adding in
*build.gradle(app)*

```
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```